# Swift: Disable Night Shift (Not Dark Mode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Is there any way I could disable `Night Shift Mode` on my application. The night shift mode messes with the overall UI and UX experience of my application (inconsistent colors).

Comment: The OP is asking about night shift (which reduces blue light), not dark mode.  As far as I know you cannot disable night shift for an application.

Comment: @RaziTiwana Could you please read the question before you down vote and mark it as duplicate - it freakin literally says Not Dark Mode!

Comment: @N.Der my bad, an honest mistake, Deleted the comment & flag. PS. the downvote isn't from my side.